# Getting Image path from dynamic javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I am displaying a page with all the product details like productname , productdetails , product image etc .Single product has many types in it.
At first only one product should be displayed . Dynamically created radio buttons based on the types . When radio button is clicked and a different type is selected image , productcolor has to be changed . i have already passed a value $color and productcolor changes accordingly . 
1.How can we change the image ?? How can we retrieve the img using the img_id???
2.After selecting the quantity , when i post cart.php , quantity values returns as 0 in cart.php.why is that happens ??

```
        <table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="300" height="600" align ="center" ><img id ="img" src="inventory_images/<?php echo $img_id; ?>.jpg" width="300" height="400" alt=""/></td>
            <br>

        <p id = "test"><?php echo $img_id; ?></p>

            <td width="150" height = "400" align="center"  >

             <p align="left"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
             <p align ="left" id = "demo"><?php echo $color; ?></p>
             <p align = "left"><?php echo $product_detail; ?></p>

             <p align = "left">Price : $<?php echo $product_price; ?></p>


              <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $color = $rows["clr"];
        $rimg_id = $rows["img_id"];



          ?>      



<ul align="left" id="menu">
<li><p onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $color; ?>' ,'<?php echo $rimg_id; ?>');"><input   type ="radio" name="radio" id ="php" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" >
<?php echo $color; ?></p>
</li>
</ul>


 <?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function myFunction(a,b) {


       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = b;
    document.getElementById("imgid").value = b;
    //document.getElementById("img").src= "inventory_images/.jpg";
       //how to get my images stored in my folder??



}
</script>

 <p align = "left" style="color:#33F">Quantity</p> <input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;' value='+'/>
<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value = '1' size = '1' />
</div><input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript: subtractQty();' value='-'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function subtractQty(){
            if(document.getElementById("qty").value - 1 < 1)
                return;
            else
                 document.getElementById("qty").value--;
        }
        </script>




              <form id = "add" name = "Add to cart" method = "POST" action = "cart.php" >
             <p><input type = "hidden" id="imgid" name = "imgid" value =""><p>  
              <p align="left"><input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit"  value = "Add to Cart" ><p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Side-info (that doesn't solve your problem yet): you create several radio's with always the same id. That won't work!

Comment: then how can i implement  this function ? how can i change the image according to the radio button?

Comment: the line where you were trying it should be: `document.getElementById("img").src= "inventory_images/"+b+".jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create one p element for each type. Do it INSIDE the while.

   ```
   <ul align="left" id="menu">
   <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       $color = $rows["clr"];
       $rimg_id = $rows["img_id"];
   ?>     
   <li>
   <p onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $color; ?>' ,'<?php echo $rimg_id; ?>');">
   <input type ="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $color; ?>">
   <?php echo $color; ?>
   </p>
   </li>
   <?php } ?>
   </ul>
   ```
2. You have to concatenate the function argument b in the image src loader:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
   function myFunction(a,b) {


   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = b;
   document.getElementById("imgid").value = b;
   document.getElementById("img").src= "inventory_images/" + b +".jpg";
      //how to get my images stored in my folder??
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Note that, if you want further processing of the form, you have to add the value property to the radio buttons. And also it would be convenient to change the `p` element to `label`, in order to display clickable text that selects the radio button.